# How to convert a string to float if the thousands and decimals points are the same

Tags: python, string, floating-point, locale, separator

I would like to convert an string like '-2.676.15024' and '2.938.45500' to float? My data base has some examples like this, where the number(string) has thousands and decimals separators with the same symbol, in these cases a point.

Comment: Is `1.125` equal to `1125` or `9/8`?

Comment: But that means that your values can be ambiguous - e.g., 2.938 Is that two thousand nine hundred and thirty eight or nearly 3?

Comment: '2.938.45500' shoud be equal to 2.938,45500, so as we have decimal places, 1.125 is equal to 9/8

Comment: Whatever you do you'll need to take into account the locale in which your code is running. In many countries the thousands separator is comma and the decimal separator is a period. In other places it's the other way around

Comment: however I have in the same column values with correct formal, comma as decimal separators, and these should not be changed.

Comment: You can adapt the answer offered by @kevic by unconditional removing commas

Comment: When working with computers, be precise. Describing a string as “like” something is insufficient. Describe all the cases: Does each string have exactly five digits after the “.” that is supposed to be the decimal point? If not, how can we know whether the last “.” is a decimal point or a group separator?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to remove all dots except the last one.

You can use a regex:

```
import re

s = '-2.676.15024'
float(re.sub('\.(?=.*\.)', '', s))
```

output: `-2676.15024`

Alternative using `rsplit` and `join`:

```
s = '-2.676.15024'
float('.'.join(map(lambda x: x.replace('.', ''), s.rsplit('.', 1))))
```

*NB. this is assuming there is always a decimal part. If not you have to clarify the conditions for deciding whether a dot is a decimal or thousand separator*

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
test = '-2.938.45500'
result = float(test.replace('.', '', test.count('.') - 1))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='-2.676.15024'
index=s.find('.')
print(float(s[:index]+s[index+1:]))
```

output:-2676.15024

Comment: 2.676.454.15024